# Improving query performance on mysql star catalog

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that contains a table with roughly 645 million records. I am trying to improve the query performance. Below is the SQL for the table as well as the indexes I use.

```
CREATE TABLE `Catalog` (
`id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sourceFile` CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
`starID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`ra` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`decl` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`muRA` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`muDecl` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magB` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magV` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magU` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magG` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magR` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magI` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magZ` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magY` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magJ` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magH` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magK` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`w1` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`w2` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`w3` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`w4` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`magSST` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`flag` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `UFilterIndex` (`magU`, `decl`, `ra`),
INDEX `GFilterIndex` (`magG`, `decl`, `ra`),
INDEX `RFilterIndex` (`magR`, `decl`, `ra`),
INDEX `IFilterIndex` (`magI`, `decl`, `ra`),
INDEX `ZFilterIndex` (`magZ`, `decl`, `ra`),
INDEX `YFilterIndex` (`magY`, `decl`, `ra`)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

My typical query looks something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Catalog` 
WHERE 
`magG` >= 7.32 AND `magG` <= 15.68 AND 
`decl` <= -1 AND `decl` >= -2 AND 
`ra` >= 75 AND `ra` <= 75.23
```

It takes on average 17 seconds to execute this query. When I EXPLAIN the query I can see that it is using the GFilterIndex using index condition. The types of queries I perform will always involve magG and decl. The queries will also involve ra the vast majority of the time. So I think my index is doing what I want it to do. When I attempt to query without the index I get query times of 8min+.

This database won't change (no inserts or updates). I will be performing thousands of these queries and at ~17 seconds each it will be very painful. Is there something I can do to further improve the query performance? Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: how many rows satisfy `magG >= 7.32 AND magG <= 15.68`? how many for `decl <= -1 AND decl >= -2` or `ra >= 75 AND ra <= 75.23`? the column giving the smallest number of matches should be first in the index. If this can change, maybe having different variants of the index with differents fields as "first" and let the optimizer pick dynamically might work. Or have 3 separate indexes and hope index_merge works well, but it usually does not..

Comment: @jkavalik I was just thinking of this. While magG is always used, decl and ra would be much better at limiting the number of rows. It takes a while to generate an index (roughly 2.5 hours). I will report back once I have some data.

Comment: Because all 3 columns are limited by a range scan and index can only effectively cover one range scan and then reads all records for the other columns (using index condition check), it may help a lot if that range scan returns significantly smaller number of rows, as the remaining columns then do not have to process as much data.

Comment: @jkavalik That did wounders. My query time is now around 0.187s which is much more manageable. Thank you. Do you want to make that an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I did. Glad it hepled.

Comment: If you don't need the precision of `DOUBLE`, `FLOAT` would save 4 bytes each.  Unless you have a huge amount of RAM, that may cut back significantly on I/O.

Comment: Is the `CHARACTER SET` defaulted to utf8?  If you need only ascii, `sourceFile` could be shrunk from 15 bytes to only 5.  This may give a small I/O improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are ranges on 3 different columns. The optimizer can only use one range scan per index. That means that the selectivity of the first column in the index is the only one which can quickly prune the rows to check, the two other conditions need to scan all these rows selected by the first one and check the conditions one by one. If you see `using index condition` in your `EXPLAIN` then at least your version can do that just by reading the columns from index. Older versions would not even use the remaining columns and would have to fetch the entire rows from the table to check them.

So when you put the most limiting column first in the index, your query will do the least work to check the remaining conditions. If your data are static, you might create multiple permutations of the index and let the optimizer pick for each query depending on the actual ranges used in conditions, but giving optimizer too many indexes might confuse it so not overdo that.

Another possibility would be to create 3 separate indexes, one for each column, and let optimizer pick `index_merge` optimization - it may scan each index separately (should be effective for ranges) and get the intersection of found rows. This optimization cannot be forced and might be even slower in some cases so you would have to test it, but your case sounds like it might be a possibly good one for that.

Other approach would be to user R-Tree index, which is supposed to handle two ranges efficiently. It is available in MySQL as *spatial index* but there are some limitations to it and it is mostly optimized for lat/long and similar searches so your data might not be the best for it - discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274648/1786423).

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `SELECT *`, try selecting the fields you need (unless you need all of them!): `SELECT id, magG, ... FROM`
2. Try to have the fields you are selecting in the used index. This way you will have a `covering index`, so the data will be read once only from the index
3. If you need many fields to be returned, you may first select the IDs using the query you already have, then send another query like this: `SELECT * FROM Catalog WHERE id IN (list of IDs from first query)` [In total, this may not be much faster, but try it to see if the difference is significant]

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your suggestions. They did provide a slight improvement but sadly, not enough for my use case.